# How can I set domainUsersCanEdit to False in a protected range?

Tags: python, google-sheets, pygsheets

I can edit the list of editors of a protected range just fine. When I create a new protected range, however, it has by default domainUsersCanEdit property set to True. How can I set it to false?

Also, related question: using Google UI you can protect the whole worksheet without setting an arbitrary range in it. Is this possible to do with pygsheets?

I failed to find answers for the above in the official API docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `domainUsersCanEdit` is set by default by the api. You can make it false by

```
range.editors = ('domainUsersCanEdit', False)
```

> Also, related question: using Google UI you can protect the whole
>   worksheet without setting an arbitrary range in it. Is this possible
>   to do with pygsheets?

Not at the moment, please raise an issue for the same.

**NB**: Please update your pygsheets from the github staging branch

Comment: Tried that but it didn't work. Upgrading to staging fixed it. I also filled a ticket for the other issue. https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets/issues/378 Also, thanks a lot for this library, it's a life saver!